# How to get XTZ on zeronet to complete a roll?

Tags: zeronet, faucet

I need to do some tests but i need enough XTZ to complete a roll in Zeronet.

Could someone explain how to get zeronet XTZ ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a one off request that is not question/answer based.

Comment: Well, it is question/answer based. Can you spare me XTZ zeronet? Yes or No. :P But ok i mean understand where your coming from.

Comment: You could reformulate the question as "How to get XTZ on zeronet to complete a roll ?"

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Faucet, as described in the documentation here : 
https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/introduction/howtouse.html#get-free-tez

Short answer,

- go to https://faucet.tzalpha.net/
- get a faucet file `tz1__xxxxxxxxx__.json`
- Activate it using `tezos-client activate account alice with "tz1__xxxxxxxxx__.json"`
- transfer or delegate the fund to your baker account